# Spacy ent.label_ cannot define organization

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am using spacy to analyze the terrorist and it is weird that spacy cannot find the organization such as fatah. The code is below

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
def read_file_to_list(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        return file.readlines()
terrorism_articles = read_file_to_list('data/rand-terrorism-dataset.txt')
terrorism_articles_nlp = [nlp(art) for art in terrorism_articles]
common_terrorist_groups = [
    'taliban', 
    'al - qaeda', 
    'hamas',  
    'fatah', 
    'plo', 
    'bilad al - rafidayn'
]

common_locations = [
    'iraq',
    'baghdad', 
    'kirkuk', 
    'mosul', 
    'afghanistan', 
    'kabul',
    'basra', 
    'palestine', 
    'gaza', 
    'israel', 
    'istanbul', 
    'beirut', 
    'pakistan'
]
location_entity_dict = defaultdict(Counter)

for article in terrorism_articles_nlp:
    
    article_terrorist_groups = [ent.lemma_ for ent in article.ents if ent.label_=='PERSON' or ent.label_ =='ORG']#人或者组织
    article_locations = [ent.lemma_ for ent in article.ents if ent.label_=='GPE']
    terrorist_common = [ent for ent in article_terrorist_groups if ent in common_terrorist_groups]
    locations_common = [ent for ent in article_locations if ent in common_locations]
    
    for found_entity in terrorist_common:
        for found_location in locations_common:
            location_entity_dict[found_entity][found_location] += 1
location_entity_dict
```

I simply get nothing from the file.
Here is [The text data link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mEbgDCzV1HTx--rn7O6KNs5sOwHh2MKO)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your example and it looks like you will get empty lists for `article_terrorist_groups` and `terrorist_common`. Therefore, you won't get the output (that I assume) you require. I changed the model (for my machine) to `en_core_web_sm` and I observed that the `ent.label` is different from ones that you are specifying in the `if` statement in your list comprehensions. I am almost certain this is the case whether you use `spacy.load('en')` or `spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`.

You are using `if ent.label_=='PERSON' or ent.label_ =='ORG'` which is leading to empty lists. You would need to change this in order for it to work. Basically, in your list comprehension for `article_terrorist_groups` and `terrorist_common`, the for loop is trying to iterate through an empty list.

If you look at the output that I posted, you will see that `ent.label` is not `'PERSON'` or `'ORG'`

Note: I would recommend adding print statements (or using a debugger) in your code to check from time to time.

**My Code**

```
import spacy
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # I changed this
def read_file_to_list(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        return file.readlines()

terrorism_articles = read_file_to_list('rand-terrorism-dataset.txt')
terrorism_articles_nlp = [nlp(art) for art in terrorism_articles]
common_terrorist_groups = [
    'taliban', 
    'al - qaeda', 
    'hamas',  
    'fatah', 
    'plo', 
    'bilad al - rafidayn'
]

common_locations = [
    'iraq',
    'baghdad', 
    'kirkuk', 
    'mosul', 
    'afghanistan', 
    'kabul',
    'basra', 
    'palestine', 
    'gaza', 
    'israel', 
    'istanbul', 
    'beirut', 
    'pakistan'
]
location_entity_dict = defaultdict(Counter)


for article in terrorism_articles_nlp:
    print([(ent.lemma_, ent.label) for ent in article.ents])
```

**Output**

```
[('CHILE', 383), ('the Santiago Binational Center', 383), ('21,000', 394)]
[('ISRAEL', 384), ('palestinian', 381), ('five', 397), ('Masada', 384)]
[('GUATEMALA', 383), ('U.S. Marines', 381), ('Guatemala City', 384)]
```

*truncated output in the interest of length of this answer*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if you check the line  "article_locations = [ent.lemma_ for ent in article.ents if ent.label_=='GPE']",you will only get'['Paris', 'Porto Vecchio', 'Corsica']' .Here GPE refers to Countries, cities, states. The spacy can't define Chile as GPE and I don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

Because groups & locations in  `common_terrorist_groups` and `common_locations` are lowercase while finded data `terrorist_common` and `locations_common`  are uppercase. So just change the code `if ent in common_terrorist_groups` to `if ent.lower() in common_terrorist_groups`

```py
common_terrorist_groups = [
    'taliban', 
    'al - qaeda', 
    'hamas',  
    'fatah', 
    'plo', 
    'bilad al - rafidayn'
]

common_locations = [
    'iraq',
    'baghdad', 
    'kirkuk', 
    'mosul', 
    'afghanistan', 
    'kabul',
    'basra', 
    'palestine', 
    'gaza', 
    'israel', 
    'istanbul', 
    'beirut', 
    'pakistan'
]
location_entity_dict = defaultdict(Counter)

for article in terrorism_articles_nlp:

    article_terrorist_cands = [ent.lemma_ for ent in article.ents if ent.label_ == 'PERSON' or ent.label_ == 'ORG']
    article_location_cands = [ent.lemma_ for ent in article.ents if ent.label_ == 'GPE']

    terrorist_candidates = [ent for ent in article_terrorist_cands if ent.lower() in common_terrorist_groups]
    location_candidates = [loc for loc in article_location_cands if loc.lower() in common_locations]
    for found_entity in terrorist_candidates:
        for found_location in location_candidates:
            location_entity_dict[found_entity][found_location] += 1
```